# Apache Camel Split - splitting header incorrectly when only one header is provided

Tags: apache-camel, splitter

I have implemented endpoint which receives multiple parameters as query

```
i.e: /flights?flight=AB,100,12FEB18&flight=CD,200,13FEB18&flight=...&...
```

In camel I would like to split each flight parameter and handle it separately, so I have:

```
.split(header("flight"))
```

### Case 1

```
Query: /flights?flight=AB,100,24FEB18&flight=AB,200,25FEB18
```

Splits into:
1) AB, 100, 24FEB18
2) AB, 200, 25FEB18

**Result: Correct**

### Case 2

```
Query: /flights?flight=AB&flight=AB,100&flight=AB,200,26FEB18
```

Splits into:
1) AB
2) AB, 100
3) AB, 200, 26FEB18

**Result: Correct**

### Case 3

```
Query: /flights?flight=AB,400,28FEB18
```

Splits into:
1) AB
2) 400
3) 28FEB18

**Result: Incorrect**

Expected: 
1) AB, 400, 28FEB18

Why does splitter for one header works differently and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess that Camel is "too smart" for your usecase and therefore you get different behaviours.

**Case 1 and 2 is a list of lists**. A list of `flight` parameters and every parameter contains a list of comma-separated values.

**Case 3 is a simple list**. A single `flight` parameter that contains a list of comma-separated values.

Since the splitter wants to split things, it takes the **"inner" list in Case 3** while it takes the **"outer" list in Case 1 and 2**.

To solve the problem you could try several things:

- Change the delimiter of the inner lists (use for example `-` instead of `,`) so that Camel does not think your `flight` parameter contains a list in Case 3.
- Add a `flight` parameter in Case 3 that is empty or contains a dummy value so that you **always have an "outer" list**.

  - Use a bean before the splitter and convert the parameter into a structure that is not mis-interpreted by the splitter

If you are not in control of the URI parameters, you could use a bean to apply one of the first two suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @burki I went with conversion of the parameter and it works. These are good suggestions.